# wpa-roam when ethernet is connected

Tags: wireless, networking, wpa-supplicant

As far as I understand, wpa-roam searches for a wifi connection when no ethernet connection is present.

I'm trying to get my Pi to take photos on a gopro over the wifi connection, but interface with the Pi over ethernet.

Is there any settings I can put in my /etc/network/interfaces to enable roaming even when an ethernet connection is present?

Current configs are as follows:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
netmask 255.255.255.0
address 192.168.2.13
gateway 192.168.2.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
iface gopro inet dhcp
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="GOPRO-BP-657282068582037"
    psk="goprohero"
    priority=5
    id_str="gopro"
}
```

I can happily connect using:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

but I'm looking to automatically associate with the GoPro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting:

```
auto wlan0
```

seemed to fix the problem